# x not in list, where x contains samples of HELLO speech

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

My code is

```
import numpy as np

from scipy import signal

import scipy.io as sio

x=np.zeros((22113,2),float)

x= sio.loadmat('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\Rabia Ahmad spring 2016\\FYP\\1. Matlab Work\\record work\\kk.mat')

h = np.array([0.9,0.3,0.1], float)

dd = signal.lfilter(h,1,x)
```

the error I encountered is **ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list**. x is the audio signal in .mat format containing **HELLO** samples.

Comment: The `np.zeros` is superfluous. Have you tried looking at the type returned by `loadmat`? Maybe it does not coincide with the type required by `lfilter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB's `.mat` files store one or more variables.  `numpy` loads those variables as a dictionary where each key corresponds to a variable name and each value corresponds to the value stored in that variable.  So `x` in your case isn't the **HELLO** samples, it is a dictionary containing at least one key and the same number of values, where at least one of the values should have your samples.  You need to get that value out and store it in `x`.

If you know the variable name ahead of time, you can just do this (assume the variable name is `'name'`):

```
x = sio.loadmat('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\Rabia Ahmad spring 2016\\FYP\\1. Matlab Work\\record work\\kk.mat')['name']
```

If you don't know the variable name, but now there will only ever be one variable in the file, you can do this:

```
myvars = sio.loadmat('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\Rabia Ahmad spring 2016\\FYP\\1. Matlab Work\\record work\\kk.mat')
x = list(myvars.values)[0]
```

Also, you don't need to define `h` as `'float'`, it will do that automatically since there are decimals in the values.  And as AreTor said, you don't need to fill `x` with `zeros` beforehand, in fact that just wastes time since that array will be immediately discarded and a new one will be created.